# wordpress loop with pagination only showing two pages

Tags: loops, pagination

I've created a loop with pagination, to show three posts per page. The pagination is only showing two pages of posts, whereas it should be showing four, as there are 11 posts altogether. The code that I'm using is taken from the WordPress Codex. I'm only just starting out with WordPress development and PHP, so my knowledge is still quite basic. Any help would be appreciated. This is what I have at the moment:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<!-- pagination -->
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
<!-- No posts found -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing posts_per_page from the query and setting this in the "Blog pages show at most" section in the Reading area in Settings.

Then in your next_post_link(), add the following conditions so it looks like this:

```
next_posts_link( 'Next Page »', $the_query->max_num_pages );
```

Note that the first argument can say whatever you want it to say. The second argument is what allows the pagination to work properly. Hope this helps.